# with() and leftjoin() in Laravel

Tags: laravel-5.5, eloquent

How can I use both `with()` and `leftjoin()` in Laravel eloquent? I would like to use in below code.

`$applicants = Applicant::with('applicant_skill')->paginate();`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `whereHas`

```
$query = Applicant::whereHas('applicant_skill', function ($q) {
            $q->where('name', 'PHP');
         })
         ->paginate(10);
```